# Javascript function to filter three different lists

Tags: javascript

I'm totally new to javascript, so excuse my noobness.

I want three different lists to get filtered according to what is typed inside a text-box. My function only sorts the first list, and only when I "get element by Id" rather than class.

My idea was to get the elements by class, and therefore get all three lists filtered, but it doesn't quite work that way. What can I do?

Javascript:

```
 <script>
    function filterList() {
        
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById('searchCombo');
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementsByClassName("drugList");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

        
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The HTML-list:

```
<input type="text" id="searchCombo" onkeyup="filterList()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul ID="list1" class="drugList">
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list2" class="drugList">
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list3" class="drugList">
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to loop over the `ul` and process them individually.

Comment: Or you could `querySelectorAll('.drugList li')` and process all of the lis at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Element.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), to filter the li elements inside drugList class. Then iterate over the elements:

```js
const nothingFound = document.querySelector('.nothingFound');
nothingFound.style.display="none";
const searchCombo = document.getElementById('searchCombo');
searchCombo.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=> {
  const {value} = e.target;
  const liElements=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".drugList li"));
  let count = 0;
  liElements.forEach(li => {
    li.style.display = "none"
    if(li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
      li.style.display = "";
      ++count;
    }
  });

  nothingFound.style.display = count > 0 ? "none": "";
});
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="searchCombo" placeholder="Search for names..">

    <ul ID="list1" class="drugList">
        <li><a href="#">List 1 element 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1 element 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1 element 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul ID="list2" class="drugList">
        <li><a href="#">List 2 element 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 2 element 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 2 element 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul ID="list3" class="drugList">
        <li><a href="#">List 3 element 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3 element 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3 element 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  <span class="nothingFound">Nothing found in this category</span>
```

Also you should consider to use css class instead of element.style.display.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly! Is there any way to add "Nothing found in this category" if the input doesn't match any li element within a ul? And is it possible to add invisible extra keywords to each li?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answer has all that much value, it borrows from @lissettdm's answer and I mainly wrote it to see what I would write. I've posted here in case it's of interest to somebody.

```js
const select_all = (selector, selectee = document) =>
  Array.from(selectee.querySelectorAll(selector));

const hide_item = item => item.style.display = 'none';
const show_item = item => item.style.display = '';
const item_text = item => item.textContent.toLowerCase() + ' ' + item.dataset.keywords;
const compare   = text => item => item_text(item).includes(text);
const has_class = class_name => item => item.className.includes(class_name);
const not_has_class = class_name => item => !has_class(class_name)(item);
const both = (pred_a, pred_b) => item => pred_a(item) && pred_b(item);

const filter_list = text => list => {
  const lis = select_all("li", list);
  
  let to_show = lis.filter(both( not_has_class('none'), compare(text) ));
  if(to_show.length === 0)
    to_show = lis.filter(has_class('none'));
  
  lis.forEach(hide_item);
  to_show.forEach(show_item);
};

const filter = (event) =>
  select_all(".drugList").forEach(
    filter_list((event?.target?.value || '').toLowerCase())
  );

document.getElementById('searchCombo').addEventListener("keyup", filter);

filter();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchCombo" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul ID="list1" class="drugList">
    <li data-keywords="additional keywords"><a href="#">List 1 element 1</a></li>
    <li data-keywords="bob fred"><a href="#">List 1 element 2</a></li>
    <li data-keywords="jane neela"><a href="#">List 1 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list2" class="drugList">
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list3" class="drugList">
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Regarding my second question with invisible extra keywords that can be searched for, I just enter the keywords with font size = 0.

<li>List 1 element 1 <font style="font-size: 0px;">extra searchable keywords here</font></li>

Maybe there's a more elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: @suverenia, my suggestion would be as included in the edit. (Although I'm not really aware about what each approach might do for SEO and things like that.)